# getStorage() method returns fatal error

Tags: entities

I think I am finally coming to the realization that the documentation for D8 is not complete enough to work with or, possibly, that OOP is simply too complex to work with unless you go through all the code of each class you want to use and trace back through everything it uses/implements.

Case in point:

I want to use this public function: public function EntityDefinitionUpdateManager::getChangeSummary

I go here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityDefinitionUpdateManager.php/function/EntityDefinitionUpdateManager%3A%3AgetChangeSummary/8.2.x

I can see its namespace is Drupal\Core\Entity

So I write this code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity;
ksm(\Drupal::EntityDefinitionUpdateManager()->getChangeSummary());
```

and woo hoo.. it works. Simple enough!!

Next: public function EntityListBuilder::getStorage

From here: it looks very similar to the previous example: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityListBuilder.php/function/EntityListBuilder%3A%3AgetStorage/8.2.x

Same namespace.

Yet, this code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity;
ksm(\Drupal::EntityListBuilder()->getStorage());
```

returns: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal::EntityListBuilder()

any idea why these cannot be implemented in the same fashion? Are there clues on the API doc pages that these will not work the same?

Answer (score 0):

A list builder only makes sense in the context of a particular entity type, you can't get one context-free. As such there's no service and no method in `\Drupal`, hence the error.

List builders come from the entity type manager service:

```
$builder = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getListBuilder('entity_type');
```

But that's a bit of a roundabout way to get to the storage object when you could just get it from the manager itself:

```
$storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('entity_type');
```

Incidentally, the `use Drupal\Core\Entity;` line is not applicable to either of your code snippets, you can remove it from both and the results wouldn't change. It almost feels like you're expecting that any class will be available via `\Drupal`, while in reality that class only exists as a static wrapper for the service container. To most people, shortcuts to often-used services.

It sounds like you might benefit from delving a bit more into how the following work:

- [PHP namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)
- [Services and dependency injection](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8)
- [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/introduction-to-entity-api-in-drupal-8)

and maybe for dessert:

- [PSR-4 namespaces and autoloading](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there are two misunderstandings in the following code shown in the question.

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity;
ksm(\Drupal::EntityDefinitionUpdateManager()->getChangeSummary());
```

1. The `use` statement doesn't require a namespace, but a full qualified class name which includes a namespace (The syntax for the `use` statement has been extended in PHP 7, but still it doesn't allow to write `use Drupal\Core\Entity;` to use all the classes in that namespace.)
2. `\Drupal::EntityDefinitionUpdateManager()` is not saying to Drupal *instantiate the `EntityDefinitionUpdateManager` class you find in the namespace I declared with the previous `use` statement*

[`\Drupal`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/class/Drupal/8.5.x) is a simple class that defines static methods. One of those static methods happens to be [`\Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityDefinitionUpdateManager/8.5.x), but the `\Drupal` class doesn't have a static method for each of the classes Drupal defines. There isn't any `\Drupal::entityListBuilder()` method, so PHP returns you an error. (Yes, PHP is not case-sensitive, so `\Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()` and `\Drupal::EntityDefinitionUpdateManager()` call the same method.)

Comment: Thanks. Good info in your answer. I was getting confused by the fact that there is a public function EntityDefinitionUpdateManager::getChangeSummary as well as a static function: Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager but sadly no list of methods. So i guess we know that the Drupal static methods are wrappers around the non-static ones and will provide the same methods?